# what would the jooq equivalent of a DDL view be?

Tags: java, sql, sql-view, jooq

I have an app going that is now implemented as a handful of views, and some jooq queries that depend on the views

why not move the whole layer into jooq? that is, implement the views in jooq? what would the smart way to do this be? and what would the performance implications be?

Answer (score 3):

There is a pending, low-priority feature request in jOOQ to support views written in jOOQ:

- [Feature request #1969](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1969).
- [Discussion on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/FhDh-kkdxhw/discussion).

You could already create the equivalent of database views by extending jOOQ:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/

Depending on your database, moving view code from the DB up to the application layer may indeed have a slight performance impact, as the DB can no longer collect statistics for a (named) view. Few databases actually do this, though, unless you create materialised views.

The advantage of keeping views written with jOOQ in Java is:

- Easier migration. You don't have to write DDL to migrate views between different versions of your application
- Advanced jOOQ feature application to views. For example, you can transform your view's SQL if need be through jOOQ's [SQL transformation SPI](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-sql-transformation/).

Comment: Is there any way I could shoe-horn this into a CustomTable or an extension of a table class? I just want to seamlessly subset the contents of a table for my API consumers but it schematically requires a join that I'd like to keep hidden.

Comment: @kylejmcintyre: Yes, the "custom query parts" link is what I meant by doing this via a `CustomTable`. It's still a bit verbose but it'll do what you want

Comment: Thanks much for your response. I'm trying to extend CustomTable but I can't figure out where to put my custom sql that subsets the rows of the main table. The docs say to extend accept(), but it's marked final in TableImpl. I can extend toSQL(), but no one is listening to it. I'm on 3.5.3. What am I doing wrong?